# How to convert Unicode to character which is displayed in web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

For example:

If I've a string which is Unicode: \u4E45

I wanna display this character to web page using JavaScript. How can I do?

And my second question is that if I've a Chinese character: 依

I wanna get its Unicode (\u4F9D) using JavaScript. How can I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is that string from? Is it JSON data?

Comment: In my question 1, the Unicode is in JSON file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inject a string with unicode characters via javascript into a webpage they will be displayed the way they should automatically (given that the browser innquestion support the display of that character).

This can be seen in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/KyuKE/1/

You can read the data in a textNode by accessing it's data property which will give you a string. This string will have the `charCodeAt` method available to get the charCode.

Example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyuKE/2/

You can read the documentation for `charCodeAt` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And do you know is there any ways to get a character's Unicode?

Answer (score 2):

Code as following

Convert utf8 to string

```
let font = '\u5b8b\u4f53';
console.log('font', font); // -> font 宋体

let str = String.raw`${font}`;
console.log('str', str);  // -> str 宋体
```

Convert string to utf8

```
function toUnicode(theString) {
  var unicodeString = '';
  for (var i=0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }
    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  }
  return unicodeString;
}

toUnicode(str[0]);  // -> '\\u5B8B'
```

I hope it helps.

Reference:

1. [Convert a String to Unicode in Javascript | Building on Mud](http://buildingonmud.blogspot.com/2009/06/convert-string-to-unicode-in-javascript.html)